# Best way for using Java inner classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

Consider the following class structure:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static class InnerClass {
    }

}
```

What is the best way to call the InnerClass (1 or 2) and why?

1)

```
import OuterClass.InnerClass;

InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();
```

2)

```
import OuterClass;

OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```

Comment: I think the choice is largely stylistic (unless it's dictated by existing or potential name clashes).

Comment: You should do what you believe is clearer.  I try not to create nested classes in other outer classes.  Doing this suggests the relationship between the outer and nested class is not that close.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The classes are not mine, I can only call them.

Comment: @NPE My point is with the 2nd approach, you are clearly precising that it is an inner class but is it worth the extra typing? Whereas with the first way, it can cause reading conflicts for other people reading the code with another outer class having the same name as the inner one.

Comment: I prefer the first way, it's cleaner and more readable IMO. Who creates public static inner classes anyway?

Comment: @Perception, you should ask the team which has provided me with these classes :P

Comment: @AdelBoutros - no need to get snarky, I never said you created them. The probability of getting a constructive answer on this question is pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer second way. In that case it is obvious that this is inner class, and programmer can always see in which class it is. In first way it is little bit "hidden". Of course you will have more typing in that case :)

Comment: Yes exactly, my point is with the 2nd approach, you are clearly precising that it is an inner class but is it worth the extra typing?